# Как настроить Denwer?

Tags: веб-сервер, denwer

Как можно настроить денвер для того, что бы по моему IP можно было подключиться к моему сайту (з.ы. у меня динамический IP и роутер)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.denwer.ru/faq/shared.html - сайт документации денвера

Answer (score 2):

Ковыряешь файл - .htaccess
Открыть порт на модеме
Заказать постоянный Ip